# Is it possible to LEFT JOIN a @variable table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

### Summary

I am attempting to LEFT JOIN on a *filtered* TABLE in SQL.

To do so I am first declaring a temporary table in an `@` variable, then attempting to join on it later.

Unfortunately I am not having much luck doing this, it massively speeds up my query when limiting to such a resultset.

### Other Routes Tried

I initially was trying to conduct this on the `WHERE`, however this was preventing rows from occurring where there were no matching `events` (I am counting the events *by* `intervals_days` so I need to return regardless of whether there's matching in the other).

After I realised my mistake, I moved to the *ON*. I have not seen examples of this done, and I have a feeling doing a FIND_IN_SET here on a SELECT would not be performant?

### QUERIES

#### The Initial Filter

```sql
DECLARE @filtered_events TABLE (id INT, eventable_id INT, eventable_type VARCHAR(255), occurred_at TIMESTAMP, finished_at TIMESTAMP)
INSERT INTO @filtered_events
SELECT
    e.id, e.eventable_id, e.eventable_type, e.occurred_at, e.finished_at
FROM
    units_events as ue
LEFT JOIN
    events as e
ON
    e.id = ue.event_id
WHERE
    ue.unit_id
IN
    (1,2,3);
```

Ignore the `(1,2,3)` here, these values are added to the query dynamically.

#### My Attempted Use Of It

```sql
SELECT
    i.starts_at as starts_at,
    i.ends_at as ends_at,
    count(fe.id) as count
FROM
    intervals_days as i
LEFT JOIN
    @filtered_events as fe
ON
    ( fe.occurred_at >= starts_at AND fe.occurred_at < ends_at )
WHERE
    ( starts_at >= '15-01-2019' AND ends_at < NOW() )
GROUP BY
    starts_at
ORDER BY
    starts_at
DESC;
```

These queries are within one SQL document, one above the other with the terminating `;` semicolon on each.

I expect this to output what my lower query outputs (a grouped resultset by the `intervals_days` rows)- however with the benefit of my LEFT JOIN query being conducted on a much smaller sample.

Comment: Mysql does not have table data type as a variable - are you sure you are using mysql? If yes, then use CTEs, temporary tables, or inline subqueries for the same purpose.

Comment: Or define a view.

Comment: @Shadow Looking through all of the documentation I've seen... no I am not using a version which supports this.

Looks like I will have to look back into the subqueries I was attempting before this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no such syntax.

MySQL has no concept of arrays, either.

Nor can you use `DECLARE` outside of a Stored Routine.

Answer (score 1):

As Shadow said in the comments, with MySQL I would use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT
    i.starts_at as starts_at,
    i.ends_at as ends_at,
    count(fe.id) as count
FROM
    intervals_days as i
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        e.id,
        e.eventable_id,
        e.eventable_type,
        e.occurred_at,
        e.finished_at
    FROM units_events as ue
    LEFT JOIN events as e
    ON e.id = ue.event_id
    WHERE ue.unit_id IN (1,2,3)
) fe
ON ( fe.occurred_at >= starts_at AND fe.occurred_at < ends_at )
WHERE ( starts_at >= '15-01-2019' AND ends_at < NOW() )
GROUP BY starts_at
ORDER BY starts_at
DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I implemented after I stopped pursuing the above